# How to set Views to show field-collection entries with not duplicated other fileds?

Tags: views, entities

I have two fields in content type. One is "link", other is "file&text"(field collection; number of values: unlimited) with two fields: "file" and "text".
Relationships:
Content: "file&text"

Problem is: Every "file&text" entry duplicate "link" field for that entry.

I tried query settings/distinct but that not make any progress.

Any tips?

Comment: Could you rephrase this in form of a question, please?